# scapy how to print a certain part of a query

Tags: python, sockets, packet, scapy, ntp

I have a NTP answer

```
from scapy.all import*
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
addr=("192.114.62.250",123)
ntp=NTP()
s.sendto(str(ntp),addr)
data,ip=s.recvfrom(1024)
data=NTP(data)
print data.recv
```

the full packet:

```
###[ NTP ]###    
leap      = nowarning    
version   = 3L    
mode      = server   
stratum   = 2L    
poll      = 10L    
precision = 235L   
delay   = 0.00489807128906  
dispersion= 0.0449066162109    
id        = 192.115.209.50    
ref       = Sat, 11 Feb 2017 17:35:59 +0000    
orig      = Sat, 11 Feb 2017 17:42:25 +0000   
****recv      = Sat, 11 Feb 2017 17:42:37 +0000****    
sent      = Sat, 11 Feb 2017 17:42:37 +0000
```

The line that i want is the on with **** but what I get is a float:

```
3695823757.8063817
```

Answer (score -1):

what you got is a time float

`import time
time.ctime(3695823757.8063817)`
should give you what you want as a tuple
to avoid confusion, by "time float" i mean seconds since epoch, you will want to use the `time` library to convert it into a different format

to get a line like you have you will need to do something like:
`time.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(3695823757.8063817)`

for more ways to represent the date please look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Comment: Can you explain how do I do I convert then into the full time?